# JBOSS V/s apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I am new to "java world", I need following clarification

- when to use JBOSS vs TOMCAT?
- differences?
- which is more reliable?
- which is more scalable?
- which is more easy to to administrate?
- does both have scale out options?
- can I host an application developed in flex on JBOSS/TOMCAT?

My application would be simple 3-tier with Servlets, so given this which is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

> *my application would be simple 3-tier with Servlets , so given this which is the best option.*

Use: Tomcat

Tomcat is a [servlet container](http://www.google.es/search?q=servlet+container) which basically serves JPS pages and servlets.

In the other hand JBoss is an [application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server) ( which inside contains a servlet container among a lot more  stuff ) and is more complex.

- when to use JBOSS vs TOMCAT?

  - Use JBoss when you need an application server, use Tomcat when you need a servlet container.
- differences?

  - One contains the other ( among other things )
- which is more reliable?

  - Both
- which is more scalable?

  - Both
- which is more easy to to administrate?

  - Tomcat
- does both have scale out options?

  - Yes
- can I host an application developed in flex on JBOSS/TOMCAT?

  - Yes

Comment: Thanks for the response . if i need to use webservices ,then which is better.

Comment: It depends on the size of your application. For very simple WS ( let's say you have to expose one table or one ... whatever )  you can use Tomcat without problems. For a larger application which requires more features ( see: http://www.jboss.com/products/platforms/application/features/ ) you could probably use JBoss, but the size of the application server ( all the options, all the features, configuration etc. ) would make it harder to use.  So, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

They are different beasts. Tomcat is a pure servlet container (meaning can run servlets and JSP mostly). JBOSS implements thte full J2EE spec, adding, for example, EJB (Enterprise Java Beans) and JMS layers, with the additional complexity that entails.

You very likely just need a servlet container like Tomcat. I recommend [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) as it's a lot simpler to handle for that use case (just servlets).

Answer (score 1):

**when to use JBOSS v/s TOMCAT ? differences?**

Basically, they are web server but Jboss is a *larger* web server. JBoss is also used for enterprise applications using Java EE technologies: JMS,EJB etc. and others like SOA, Webservices. Jboss usually is called Application Server (different from Web server).

**which is more reliable ? which is more scalable?**
Both. It depends on your application

**which is more easy to to administrate?**
Tomcat

**does both have scale out options?**
Yes

**can i host an application developed in flex on JBOSS/TOMCAT?**
Yes, any of them

**my application would be simple 3-tier with Servlets , so given this which is the best option**
You did not mention what your tiers are so for the begining I suggest TOMCAT

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a servlet container. JBoss is a J2EE container. It *uses* Tomcat as its servlet container. So the question doesn't actually make much sense.

Comment: *It uses* [a forked version of] *Tomcat as its servlet container.*

Answer (score 0):

What type of Java app server should you choose for your next project? Well, that kinda depends on what kind of app you’re building, what your needs are, what type of organization you work in, and lots of other factors too pls check below link

`http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/`